# Array gets garbage value when i try function overloading

Tags: c++, arrays, overloading

I'm trying to calculate the arithmetic means of 2 arrays of numbers (one of type 'float', the other 'int') using two functions named the same.
For some reason, when I run the full program, one of the arrays gives me garbage value for mean.
Code shown below -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// function declarations
float Mean (float[ ], int);
float Mean (int[ ], int);
//float SD (int[ ], int);
//float SD (float[ ], int size = 15);

int main( )
{
int Fib [15] = {0}; //declare and initialize the Fibonacci array
float Array[100] = {1.0,0.0}; //declare and initialize the floating point array

int sizeFib = sizeof(Fib)/sizeof(int);
int sizeArray = sizeof(Array)/sizeof(float);

//set float precision
cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
cout.precision(2);

//generate the Fibonacci array
Fib[0] = 0; //by definition
Fib[1] = 1; //by definition
for (int i = 2; i < 15; ++i)
    Fib[i] = Fib[i-2] + Fib[i-1];

//generate the floating point array
for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
    Array [j + 1] = Array[j] + 1 ;

//for (int k = 0; k < sizeArray; ++k)
    //cout << Array[k]<< endl;

cout << "The Arithmetic Mean of the Floating point Array is :" << Mean(Array, sizeArray) << endl;
cout << "The Arithmetic Mean of the Fibonacci Array is :" << Mean(Fib, sizeFib) << endl;

return 0;
}

//function definitions
float Mean (int array[ ], int size)
{
int sum = 0;
float mean;
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    sum += array[i];
}
mean = sum / size;
return mean;
}

float Mean (float array[ ], int size)
{
int sum = 0;
float mean;
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    sum += array[i];
}
mean = sum / size;
return mean;
}
```

The output I get when I run this is -

The Arithmetic Mean of the Floating point Array is :50.00

The Arithmetic Mean of the Fibonacci Array is:74702368.00

Why is the Fibonacci Array crapping out?

Comment: `Array [j + 1] = ...` - ask yourself what that indexes when `j` is at the top of its loop (99). Now, how big was `Array` again? You're indexing out of bounds, invoking undefined behavior in the process.

Comment: I guess this is some exercise some you probably have to implement by yourself, but should you need to sum iterables in the future, [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is provided in stl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is in this code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
    Array [j + 1] = Array[j] + 1 ;
```

The last iteration of this loop will try to set `Array[100]` to a floating-point value. But this is out of the bounds of the array, and what it actually seems to be doing is setting the *first* element of the `Fib` array to that value! (I guess the compiler chose to place the `Fib` array immediately after the `Array` array in memory.)

Since the `Fib` array contains ints, and this is writing a float value, you end up with a huge integer that looks like garbage when it gets interpreted as an `int`. Specifically, the float `100.0` is getting interpreted as the int `1120403456` (because those values have the same bit representation in memory).

I suggest generating the `Array` array similar to how you generate the `Fib` array, by defining the first value of the array and then setting each of the rest of the values based on the previous value:

```
Array[0] = 0;
for (int j = 1; j < 100; ++j)
    Array[j] = Array[j - 1] + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are summing float values into integer value.
After that, you are dividing two integers and expecting a float value. If both operands of an operator are the same type, the operator will work with those types. The conversion to float will be later, during assignment, not during the division.

However the insane number you get is due to out-of-bounds error, as @WhozCraig pointed out.